# Scaffolding in Visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying to develop a code generation utility in which I need to invoke creation of controllers and views from command line in VS 2013. I tried MvcScaffolding package but I am getting errors while installing. Is there any option in VS 2013 to create controllers and views by command line.?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this package was discontinued because Visual Studio 2013 doesn't have support for [`EnvDTE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/envdte.aspx).

Now Microsoft Team only provides support for built-in scaffolding (based on [SideWaffle](http://sidewaffle.com/) plugins).

---

**UPDATE**

[There's a fix for MVcScaffolding in VS2013 and V2015 here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcScaffolding.VS2015/).